# How to Consolidate 12 Data Frames in R

Tags: merge, union, union-all

Newbie here.
How would I be able to consolidate 12 data frames in R. I assigned each csv file a data frame(one for each month for the entire 2023).
Ex. Jan2023 <- read_csv(c:...Jan2023.csv
Since, each file contains the same column names, I'd like to be able to consolidate those so I can start cleaning just 1 file - the consolidated one.
I tried using `union_all` however, I am getting an error. Here's what my code looks like with the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qgrA.png)